# Is there any plugin for calendar that can be shown up without any event

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I want to show a calendar at the top of page. I googled it and got some results but all of them would shown up after some events such as 'click', 'mousemove' , etc.

I want to find a plugin can satisfied with following requirements.

1. It can be show up while the document is ready and will not disppear
2. It has the api of listening the click event (click day or change month,year)

BTW： I don't need a calendar like Google Calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery datepicker

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: How to show up while the document is ready? I found it need a input field

Comment: it's doesn't necessarily use an input field, you can attach it to a div or a span and open it like this:

    $(function(){
        $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "show" );
    });